# Input masking in Sqlite

Tags: sqlite, check-constraints

How can I restrict the input of the registration number column to a specific format of AB-78. The first 2 characters must be alphabets and the last two numbers. I tried like [A-Z][A-Z]-[0-9][0-9] but it didn't work in SQLite.

Comment: If your version of SQLite support `REGEXP`, then use `REGEXP '^[A-Z]{2}.*[0-9]{2}$'` ... otherwise, this is not easily handled.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  But it's not only if the version supports REGEXP, the sqlite3 library allows a custom function to be bound to the REGEXP function.  In other words, if it is not already supported you might be able to implement your own depending on your host language.  Provide more detail about that.

Answer (score 3):

Use the GLOB operator.  It supports a limited set of matching patterns.  You could add a CHECK constraint in the column definition (e.g. as part of the CREATE TABLE statement) that includes a GLOB expression, similar to

```sql
CHECK (column GLOB '[A-Za-z][A-Za-z]-[0-9][0-9]')
```

GLOB patterns are case sensitive, so I included both ranges of uppercase and lowercase characters.  If you need a particular case, then just remove the other range in the character class.

See [online docs](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html) for more information about LIKE, REGEXP and GLOB.  Information on GLOB patterns can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) or doing a web search.  There are many pages with more information.  I don't think the built-in GLOB function supports all named character classes.

Comment: Nice one, I'll try to remember `GLOB` next time I see a SQLite regex question :-)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  :)  It is very limited however, just supports character classes and single-character repetitions.  It is not a true regular expression function.